# .each jQuery iterator calling a normal function, why not?

Tags: jquery

I need to use/reuse a external (normal) function into the jQuery.each(), like this:

```js
function foo(index,ele){
    if(!($(ele).attr("href")) || $(ele).attr("href") == "") {
        $(ele).addClass("yellow");
    }        
}
// INCORRECT, but WHY??
$("a").each(foo(index,domEle));
```

[Here a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zTF22/) with correct and incorrect cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're passing the result of the function execution, not the function itself

```
$("a").each(foo); // <-- this is how it should be written
```

in this case a reference to the function is passed and everything works as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/zTF22/1/